# SQL Query to Select the 'Next' record (similar to First or Top N)

Tags: sql, database, select, top-n

I need to do a query to return the next (or prev) record if a certain record is not present. For instance consider the following table:

```
ID (primary key)    value
1                    John
3                    Bob
9                    Mike
10                   Tom.
```

I'd like to query a record that has id 7 or greater if 7 is not present.

My questions are,

1. Are these type of queries possible with SQL?
2. What are such queries called in the DB world?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the query to return only `9 Mike` if you search for `7` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but implementation will depend on your RDBMS.

Here's what it looks like in MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite:

```
select ID, value
from YourTable
where id >= 7
order by id
limit 1
```

In MS SQL-Server, Sybase and MS-Access:

```
select top 1 ID, value
from YourTable
where id >= 7
order by id
```

In Oracle:

```
select * from (
    select ID, value
    from YourTable
    where id >= 7 
    order by id
)
where rownum = 1
```

In Firebird and Informix:

```
select first 1 ID, value
from YourTable
where id >= 7
order by id
```

In DB/2 (this syntax is in SQL-2008 standard):

```
select id, value
from YourTable
where id >= 7
order by id
fetch first 1 rows only
```

In those RDBMS that have "window" functions (in SQL-2003 standard):

```
select ID, Value
from (
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rownumber,
    Id, Value
  from YourTable
  where id >= 7
) as tmp                  --- remove the "as" for Oracle
where rownumber = 1
```

And if you are not sure which RDBMS you have:

```
select ID, value
from YourTable
where id = 
      ( select min(id)
        from YourTable
        where id >= 7
      )
```

Comment: Just added SQLite and Informix to the list.

Comment: And window function solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for MS-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
id, value 
FROM your_table
WHERE id >= 7
ORDER BY id
```

or for MySql

```
SELECT id, value 
FROM your_table
WHERE id >= 7
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do it like this:

```
select top 1 * from myTable where id >=7
order by id
```

implementation of the `top 1` part is T-SQL (MSSQL/Sybase), other implementations vary but it is always possible (mysql/postgre `LIMIT 1`, oracle `rownum = 1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from Persons where Id >= @Id order by Id
```