# SQL Select the first x rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query to Select First/Top N records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680672/sql-query-to-select-first-top-n-records)

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT WeekNumber, SUM(Hours)
FROM Information
WHERE YEAR = 2011
GROUP BY WeekNumber
ORDER BY WeekNumber DESC
```

However; I am trying to select either the information for the last week, or the last month.  Is there a way to select just the first row, or the first x rows, where those rows contain the  hours for that month?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680672/sql-query-to-select-first-top-n-records/7680733#7680733 is the answer for this question in multiple RDBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, use the `TOP` clause (`limit` is only for MySQL); e.g.:

```
SELECT TOP 10 WeekNumber, SUM(Hours)
FROM Information 
WHERE YEAR = 2011
GROUP BY WeekNumber
ORDER BY WeekNumber DESC
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the TOP clause dynamic, where it will change according to what week it is?

Comment: @brachaalizah That makes no sense, weeknumber is potentially different for each row, the top x clause applies to the whole query

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (as specified in your tags), you need to use the `TOP` keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 10 WeekNumber, SUM(Hours)
FROM Information
WHERE YEAR = 2011
GROUP BY WeekNumber
ORDER BY WeekNumber DESC
```

The `LIMIT` keyword is for MySQL, not for SQL Server

You may also use `SET ROWCOUNT 10` at the very start of your query, which does the same thing but will last for all subsequent queries in the connection.