# What is the best and simplest SQL Query to get the Best 3 scores and their corresponding details.

Tags: sql

I have a table 'results' in which the scores are stored. Its ordered by the date of `test'. Now i need to get the details of the users who have secured 1st , 2nd and 3rd in the test.

i suppose that to get the 1st score i can use:

```
select *
from RESULTS
where SCORE=max(SCORE)
```

But what about for 2nd and 3rd. 
Also is it possible to get the three of them together in a single query.

Comment: `where SCORE=max(SCORE)` is not correct syntax anyway. It should be `where SCORE = (select max(SCORE) from RESULTS)`

Comment: i thought was good enough. What is the correction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try (MySql)

```
SELECT * FROM results
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3
```

or (MS-SQL)

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM results
ORDER BY score DESC
```

or (Oracle)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM results
     ORDER BY score DESC) t
WHERE ROWNUM < 4
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add an Oracle `ROWNUM` version too to your answer?

Comment: @Rohit: does my answer address your problem?

Comment: [Vendor specific "FETCH FIRST"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause)

Comment: This site is even better: [Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-simple)

Comment: @ypercube: both pages on my favourites :) Thanks

Comment: And this SO question on the same problem (top 1 row): [SQL Query to Select First/Top N records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680672/sql-query-to-select-first-top-n-records)